# multicolor bar chart ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I am trying have a multicolor bar chart, but scale_fill_manual or scale_color_brewer etc. do neither work outside or inside geom_bar -> Can sb help, please?

```
ggplot(data=sust_future, aes(x=as.factor(`sust.self-perception`))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),width=0.6) +  
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) + 
  labs(title = "xxx", x = "", y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=8),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want the bars to be coloured (for example based on a factor in a column or based on some other conditions). If you are trying to colour your geom_bar based on something in your data, you'd have to define how you'd like to colour in your bars via `aes(fill = column_name)` either globally in `ggplot()` or specifically in `geom_bar()`. Here is an example you can try to implement in your case (as I do not know what is in `sust_future`:

```
# global setting
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_bar()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))

# local to geom_bar
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Species))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now, I just did not know that I had to specify "fill=...".